# Insert images from URL

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have been using the below macro in Excel for years with no issues, but it no longer works as of today. Any help would be greatly appreciated.   The macro was used to insert an image into a cell from a URL link.

Try running the macro using the below two unique URLs. URL #1 used to work, but URL #2 will only wor.

1. https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=40635&c=5040682&h=apoQ4huHLAwj5ZuOlYD4qN7dcY6tFcHthCj7xBlIow5p71IJ

- this URL stopped working.   I used this macro with no issues to pull images from NetSuite URLs for 4 years with no issues.

2. https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0991/4740/products/media_9f5fad77-14c4-4c09-99a2-e99771eda949_2048x.jpg?v=1636968278 - this URL works with the macro

```vb
Sub Netsuite_Image_ATS()
   
    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    Dim filenam As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3)(1))
    For Each cell In Rng
        filenam = cell.Value
        If filenam <> "" Then
            xCol = cell.Column + 1
            Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=filenam, _
                LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
                Left:=xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - 100) / 2, _
                Top:=xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - 100) / 2, _
                Width:=100, _
                Height:=100

        Else
            Set Pshp = Nothing
            Range("B2").Select
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Have seen various comments here that O365 recently switched to disabling older macros (Excel 4.0) by default. Not sure if it's applicable here, but might be? If not, then perhaps expand on what "no longer works" means. i.e.: Are you seeing an error, and (if so), where?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try running the macro using the below two unique URLs.   One of the will work and the other will not.

1) https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=40635&c=5040682&h=apoQ4huHLAwj5ZuOlYD4qN7dcY6tFcHthCj7xBlIow5p71IJ  - this one will not work

2) https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0991/4740/products/media_9f5fad77-14c4-4c09-99a2-e99771eda949_2048x.jpg?v=1636968278 - this one will work


I have no idea why the macro only stopped working on URL #1 above

Comment: If one URL works and another doesn't,  that would suggest it's related to the images or web sites.  Perhaps image file type, or restrictions on the web sites.  What steps have you taken to investigate that?

Comment: I have already reached out to NetSuite and Shopify.   No restrictions on either.

I can download the image manually using the NetSuite URL with no issues, but for some reason the macro won't pick it up.